# Pack an html5/css3/js based ebook to android/iOS app (no epub)

Tags: android, html, web-applications, epub

I'm currently creating an ebook in html5/css3/js (jquery) and I'm looking for a solution to pack it as an application (android/iOS) or a web-application.

- Epub format isn't enough powerfull for the differents features I've developped.
- PhoneGap only support light weight applications (15Mo), and I've plenty pictures.
- Titanium seems complexe (I just want my html pages to be readable as in the browser)

Is there any solution to pack it "quite" simply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 15MB limit on PhoneGap applies only to PhoneGap Build; if you install it locally, you can compile an arbitrary-sized app. I strongly suggest PhoneGap for your task.

Comment: I'm finally using the Cordova project (aka Phonegap). Thanks for your answer.